# Google Sheets change tab name based on cell value of a DIFFERENT tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok so I currently am running this script which works perfect if you make an edit on the current tab you're wanting to change the sheet name for...

```
    function onEdit(e) {
if(e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'A1') return;
    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet()
            s.setName(s.getRange('A1')
                .getValue())
}
```

What I tried to do is use a query formula that will change the cell value based on the cell of a different tab.  That didn't work, because it's not them making an edit.  It's happening automatically when the cell in a different tab changes.  Is there any script that would allow me to change the tab name based on the value of a cell from a different tab?

Maybe I need to be using OnChange instead?  Does anyone have an example to make OnChange do the same thing?

Comment: The are no triggers that respond to changes made by scripts or formulas

Comment: Yea I know, that's what I'm needing help with.  Was hoping for an example of a trigger.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Is there any script that would allow me to change the tab name based on the value of a cell from a different tab?`. Can I ask you about the detail of both your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Sure, example: Sheet1 and Sheet2.  I want to change the name of Sheet2 based on the cell value of B2 on Sheet1 anytime it's changed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal from `Sheet1 and Sheet2. I want to change the name of Sheet2 based on the cell value of B2 on Sheet1 anytime it's changed.`. When the cell B2 of "Sheet1" is changed, you want to change the sheet name of "Sheet2" (In this case, this is 2nd tab?). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how is the cell "B2" of Sheet1" changed?

Comment: Manually by the user.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm my understanding of your question. In your question, when an user manually change a cell "B2" of "Sheet1", you want to change the sheet name of 2nd tab. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the page you'd like to rename as a variable as follows

> const sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[1]

and call it.

Here is a simple example code:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
const sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[1]

function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetId() == sheet1.getSheetId() 
  && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A1') sheet2.setName(e.value)
}
```

And [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14EQP1rQS38h0zw_2VEOldZpK9oYild_hDBVok05TUT0/edit?usp=sharing) is a working example sheet.

Comment: That works perfectly BUT my question now is can it do it on change instead of on edit?

Comment: Actually, could this be run on a time trigger?  Is there a time trigger code I can use

Comment: Mmm do you need to a time-based trigger that should look at a certain cell and rename a certain page with that cell's value?